# PdfConverter in Android won't load local images

Tags: android, pdf-conversion

I'm trying to generate a pdf from HTML code using images stored in memory. The URIs are correct and the files exist. With WebView, we can use `webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);`in order to allow it to access files to manage them properly but, when it comes to [PdfConverter](https://github.com/blink22/react-native-html-to-pdf/blob/master/android/src/main/java/android/print/PdfConverter.java), it seems like there is no option to allow access to files and, thereby, the images don't appear at all in the pdf generated. The PdfConverter uses a WebView and I tried to add the prior line of code to it, but it didn't do the trick.

What's the workaround for this?

```
private void shareOrder(String html) {
    PdfConverter converter = PdfConverter.getInstance();
    String fileName = "foo.pdf"
    File file = new File(getCacheDir(), fileName);
    converter.convert(this, html, file);

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();

    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
    if (uri != null) {
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION); // temp permission for receiving app to read this file
        shareIntent.setDataAndType(uri, getContentResolver().getType(uri));
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getString(R.string.send_to)));
    } else {
        Log.e("PreviewOrder", "URI not found");
    }
    send(true);
    finish();
}
```

HTML to be converted (keep in mind that the APPLICATION_ID is the package name of the actual project):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <tr>
      <td width='100%' colspan='1' style='padding: 10px 0px;'>
        <h3 style='position: absolute;  top: -10px; color:red;'>Draft</h3>
      </td>
      <td width='100%' colspan='1' style='padding: 10px 0px;'>
        <p align='right' style='position: relative;'>Generated by <a target='_blank' href='https://example.com/'><b>https://example.com/</b></a></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <img
      style='height:auto;max-width:150px;' src='file:///data/user/0/[APPLICATION_ID]/cache/orders_logo.jpg' onerror='this.style.display = \"none\"'>
    <div  style='font-size:25px;font-weight: bold;'>Company name</div>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table width='100%'>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width='100%' colspan='2'>
            <hr style='border-color:black; border-width: 2px;'>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='100%' colspan='2' style='padding: 10px 0px;'>COMPANY</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color:LightGray;">
          <td width='100%' style='border-bottom: 1px solid black;font-weight:bold;' colspan='2'>Order Details</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='100%' colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='50%'>Client:</td>
          <td width='50%' style='font-weight:bold;'>CLIENT</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='50%'>Date:</td>
          <td width='50%' >DATE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='50%'>User:</td>
          <td width='50%'>(44) <b>USER</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='50%' style='vertical-align: top;'>Address:</td>
          <td width='50%' id='dir'>ADDRESS</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='50%' style='vertical-align:top;'>Map:</td>
          <td width='50%'><a target='_blank' href='https://www.google.com/maps?q=0,0'><img width='100%' style='margin-top: 5px; max-width: 300px; height: auto;' src='file:///data/user/0/[APPLICATION_ID]/cache/map.png'></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="50%">Client Id: </td>
          <td width="50%">ID</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="background-color:LightGray;">
          <td width='100%' style='border-bottom: 1px solid black;font-weight:bold;' colspan='2'>Products details</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='100%' colspan='2'>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan='2'>
            <table border='1' style='border-spacing:0px;border-collapse: collapse;' cellspacing='0'cellpadding='0' width='100%'>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th width='10%'>SKU</th>
                  <th width='40%'>Product name</th>
                  <th width='25%'>Price</th>
                  <th width='10%'>Quantity</th>
                  <th width='10%'>Discount</th>
                  <th width='25%'>Total price</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>ID</td>
                  <td>PRODUCT</td>
                  <td align="center">PRICE</td>
                  <td align="center">QUANTITY</td>
                  <td align="center">DISCOUNT</td>
                  <td align="right">TOTAL</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='20%'>Total:</td>
          <td width='10%' style='text-align:right;'>Total: 989.85 €</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width='50%' style='vertical-align:top;'>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Pdf generated by PdfConverter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSM21.jpg)

[This is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plolE.jpg)

Comment: Why are you even talking about WebView if you are busy with PdfConverter? What does it convert to what? What should happen? Tell what you are doing?

Comment: @blackapps Because PdfConverter uses WebView and, even though I tried to add ```.setAllowFileAccess(true);``` to the PdfConverter class, I haven't been able to get it working. I'm trying to generate a pdf from HTML code.

Comment: Well show your code. And then it is a HtmlConvertor i would say and it generates Pdf. Why not told in your post?

Comment: Also tell how it uses webview as i would think it could convert a html file just by the file. Can you give a link to that PdfConverter?

Comment: @blackapps I provided an hyperlink on the original post, but I'll post the link here as well: https://github.com/blink22/react-native-html-to-pdf/blob/master/android/src/main/java/android/print/PdfConverter.java

Comment: Sorry that i did not see that before. Now please tell what this `html` parameter is. And what it contains. And how you filled it. Better: show more code.

Comment: @blackapps I added more code to the question

Comment: I think you spent a lot of time in vain as it looks as the `img` tag is not supported. From your link: `react-native-html-to-pdf Convert html strings to PDF documents using React Native`. Even only small stings. Yours is well vonverted but i tried bigger source strings and they fail... mmm... if that is the reason. You better contact the developer.

Comment: From the examples: `String htmlString = options.hasKey("html") ? options.getString("html") : null;` So small strings. If it would support images you would not have to add that support line...
`

Comment: https://pspdfkit.com/guides/android/generating-pdfs/generating-pdf-from-html/

Comment: @blackapps Thank you, I'll take a look at it

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it implementing these two dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.tom-roush:pdfbox-android:1.8.10.3'
implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
```

Then, in the `PdfConverter` class, I replaced the one that I took from the link indicated in my question by [this one](https://github.com/christopherdro/react-native-html-to-pdf/blob/master/android/src/main/java/android/print/PdfConverter.java).

To convert the HTML to pdf, I did the following:

```
PdfConverter converter = PdfConverter.getInstance();
String fileName = "foo.pdf";
File file = new File(getCacheDir(), fileName);
try {
    converter.convert(this, html, file, true, null, null, null);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Conversion from HTML to PDF unsuccessful");
}
```